# Count instances of a phrase in each row using full text search

Tags: c#, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

I'm looking for a way to find frequency of a word or a phrase in table.

There are some simple ways discussed (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21946766/942659)), but they are not using full text serach; and since I'm going to do this on a big table, performance is a major concern.

Another idea might be finding rows which contains that word or phrase with full text search:

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Title, '"my phrase"')
```

... and then calculate frequency by the method above or in code behind in C#.

But it doesn't seem to be a good idea.

So, is there any better way to calculate repeat count of a word or phrase in each row using full text search?

---

**Update:** From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103313/942659) answer (Thanks @JodyT), I found out that full text actually stores occurrences of each word for each row, so something like this does the job:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document
( 
    DB_ID('MyDb'),     
    OBJECT_ID('MyTable') 
)
WHERE document_id=1139
AND display_term='phrase'
```

So it works well for *words*, but not for **phrases**. For example, I might want to find out occurrences of phrase `visual studio` in each row.

Since I'm extracting common phrases in other part of my project, is there a way to tell full text search to index those common phrases (that I extracted and stored in another table) too?

If not, what else can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get word frequencies from SQL Server Full Text Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739391/get-word-frequencies-from-sql-server-full-text-search)

Comment: @JodyT I might not understood that answer correctly, but it seems that in what the answer explains there's no way in that answer to get a word frequency number for *each* row.

Comment: According to the desciption of the MSDN page `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` should be able to return the count for each row.

Comment: @JodyT Sorry, my mistake. I updated my question.